# Creating a Jboss node apart from default node

Tags: jboss

How to create a new Jboss node .

I am using jboss app server. Need to configure another node apart from default node.
How can it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to create **JBoss Node**. You can use Admin panel to add a node or You can manually changes code(xml) in domail.xml and host.xml to add a node.

http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/06/29/managing-cluster-nodes-in-domain-mode-of-jboss-as-7-eap-6/